# How to Initialize FIPS mode with FIPS_mode_set() on Windows 64 Platform with openssl-1.0.2n and openssl-fips-2.0.16

Tags: windows, openssl, fips

I am a C++ beginner. I want to build, install and initialize FIPS mode on an application using OpenSSL. I have been following the instructions in the [user manual](https://www.openssl.org/docs/fips/UserGuide-2.0.pdf). I understand that to initialize FIPS I need to follow the instructions in  5.2 FIPS Mode Initialization. However, I need more details on how to execute these instructions. I am not sure where should I embed the code mentioned in Option 1: Direct call to FIPS_mode_set() or Option 2: Indirect call via OPENSSL_config()

I was able to build FIPS using instructions 4.3 Building and Installing the FIPS Object Module with OpenSSL (Windows) in the manual. Simply by following along the lines.

Comment: The user manual
https://www.openssl.org/docs/fips/UserGuide-2.0.pdf

Comment: Call `FIPS_mode_set(1)` if you want to do it from code. You should do it in your code before any operation that needs to run in *FIPS* mode.

Comment: So, were you able to do it?

Comment: @CrisFati , not really but no worries. It was done. Thank you sir.